# Migrate messed up UTF-8 character codes in PostgreSQL JSON

Tags: postgresql

After a DB restore something weird has happened with character codes in JSONB columns.
Now the data looks like:

`{"town": "KARLSTAD", "county": {"code": "GR17", "name": "VÃ¤rmland"}, "address": "DÃ¤r VÃ¤ster SnÃ¥rstad 506", "country": {"code": "SE", "name": "Sweden"}, "postal_code": "65593", "municipality": {"code": "GK1780", "name": "Karlstad"}}`

There are charter-code/code-page mixu-ps in the data as the values should use Swedish characters:

`{"town": "KARLSTAD", "county": {"code": "GR17", "name": "Värmland"}, "address": "Där Väster Snårstad 506", "country": {"code": "SE", "name": "Sweden"}, "postal_code": "65593", "municipality": {"code": "GK1780", "name": "Karlstad"}}`

The codes seems to be consistent as the Swedish `ä` is always `Ã¤` (hex: C3 83 C2 A4). `å` is hex: C3 83 C2 A5 and the `ö` is hex: C3 83 C2 B6...

Is there a way to 1) replace all instances "safely" to restore the true characters from the failed ones and 2) figure out why this happened and only affects JSONB columns?

Answer (score 0):

Well, question #1 I figured out:

```
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã¶', 'ö')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã¤', 'ä')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã¥', 'å')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã–', 'Ö')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã„', 'Ä')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã…', 'Å')::jsonb;
update supplier set visiting_address = replace(visiting_address::text, 'Ã©', 'é')::jsonb;
```

I exported the table as SQL and search for `Ã` (hex: C3) to find a few others as well, e.g. `ü`, `õ` which also falls outside of the 127 ASCII tables...

Question #2 is still very much interesting though, why did this happen?